# How to rerender PDF.js page with different scale?

Tags: pdf.js

I'm trying just to run the same procedure, but with different scale. But it gives me broken pictures. So what is the correct way to update scale?

```
function draw(num, scale) {
    pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function(page) {
        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
        var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        var renderContext = {
          canvasContext: context,
          viewport: viewport
        };
        page.render(renderContext);
    }
}
draw(1, 1);
draw(1, 2);
```

Comment: The operations you are using are async -- you have to wait until rendering is done (via Promises) or use different canvas. See http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/